# Haskell deriving Show for custom type

Tags: haskell, instance, show

How can I tell haskell that when `show` is called on a list of variables of algebraic type, a "\n" should be inserted after each line?

```
type Customer = (Int, Int, [Int])
```

I tried to do this:

```
instance of Show Customer where
show x = x ++ "\n"
```

but apparently I can only create such instances for "data...." kind of things. How can I solve this?

I need to derive `Show` just for a list of Customers, so that when I display it, the output is easily readable, one customer per line.

Answer (score 10):

To just display on different lines, don't change `show`, just do `unlines (map show customerList)`. This will show each of them, then put them back together with newline characters inbetween.

---

However, you asked about changing show for a `type` synonym, so here are your options for that:

`show` is for basic serialisation of the data. If you want to do something different, you've got a few options:

1. Write a function that does it in this instance.
2. Make your own Display class and define how you like to lay things out in its `display` function.
3. Use a `newtype` to wrap the data.
4. Declare your own customer type.
5. Add newlines later

   type Customer = (Int, Int, [Int])

**Example 1**

```
displayC :: Customer -> String
displayC = (++"\n").show
```

**Example 2**

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances,  FlexibleInstances #-}
class Display a where
  display :: a -> String

instance Display Customer where
   display x = show x ++ "\n"
```

(Notice you should say `instance Display Customer` rather than `instance of Display Customer`.)

Example output:

```
*Main> display ((3,4,[5,6])::Customer)
"(3,4,[5,6])\n"
```

Those language extensions should be used with caution, though.

**Example 3**

```
newtype Cust = Cust Customer
displayCust (Cust c) = show c ++ "\n"
```

**Example 4**

```
data CustomerTup = CTup Int Int [Int]
displayCTup (CTup a b cs) = show (a,b,cs) ++ "\n"
```

or even better,

```
data CustomerRec = CRec {custno::Int, custAge::Int, custMeasurements::[Int]}
  deriving Show
displayCRec r = show (custno r,custAge r,custMeasurements r) ++ "\n"
```

where you might even stick with the `Show` instance way of doing things. The `data` way is good because there's more type safety, and the record type stops you making trivial wrong position mistakes.

**Example 5**

```
stuff = unlines $ map show  [(1,2,[3,4]),(5,6,[7,8,9])]
```

or even

```
morestuff = unlines [show (1,2,[3,4]), 
                     show (5,6,[7,8,9]),
                     "are all more numbery than",
                     show (True,4,False)]
```

Comment: That won't work; you still won't be able to make `Customer` an instance of your `Display` class because `Customer` is a type synonym.

Comment: How did you write this up in two minutes? :o

Comment: @Tarrasch I wrote a program writing program writing program. Recursion's quite handy, you know.

Comment: @Tarrasch Only joking, I was writing it up for longer. Click on the __edited__ time link to see the timings of each edit. Actually, I did actually write a program writing program writing program, years ago, but that was before they invented scrap your boilerplate and template haskell. It parsed rich text format files where the style/colour of the text indicated whether it represented a value in the program, the program writing program or the program writing program writing program.

Comment: Wish I could upvote twice, once for the right advice and once for the correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

A small addition to AndrewC's excellent answer:

**6.** Write a function that adds a new line to the textual representation of any type in the class `Show`:

```
display :: Show a => a -> String
display = flip shows "\n"
```

For example:

```
> display (2, 3, [5, 7, 11])
"(2,3,[5,7,11])\n"
```

Comment: That's neat code. I thought it should be 1(b), so I renumbered, but I see now that you _do_ mean something different, to rolled my edit back to it being option 6.

Comment: it does not work how I expected. The list is still being displayed the same way, with "\n" sticked in between

Comment: @user1166935 What do you mean? Do you want to actually write the string to be printed to the terminal. Try: `display' x = putStr (display x)`.